# What macOS mail applications support a "Send Only" email account?

Tags: mail.app, email, smtp

I'd like to revisit a question which has come up before (more on that below), but which does not, in my opinion, have a good “future-proof” solution looking forward to 2019 and beyond.

#### “Send Only” Email Accounts

For years I have used [Mailsmith as a “send only” email app](https://www.engadget.com/2011/06/18/use-mailsmith-to-create-a-send-only-email-account/), and it works very well. The primary reason for this is that it understands the concept of a “send only” account -- an account which is specifically set-up in such a way that the app will be used to *send* but not *receive* email.

#### The Problem

The problem is that Mailsmith is 32-bit, and [according to its own homepage](https://www.mailsmith.org) “will not be upgraded for 64-bit macOS compatibility.” That means it will throw a warning in Mojave when first launched (no big deal) but will probably cease to work in the next version of OS X (big deal).

#### What I’m Looking For

- Because I can register Mailsmith as my default mail application, it will handle `mailto:` links on web pages, or any actions which want to send mail through a regular Mac email app.
- I can setup multiple accounts in Mailsmith (work, personal, etc) and have the correct “From:” address be used when the email is sent.
- Mailsmith integrates with my Contacts.app address book, so it will auto-complete email addresses as I type them.
- Mailsmith can save Drafts on the SMTP server, and properly adds sent emails to the “Sent” folder on the SMTP server.

#### Previous Suggestions.

As I mentioned, this question has come up before, but none of the proposed solutions address the above points.

For example:

1. [Setup another mail account and delete all email sent to it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110140/apple-mail-send-only-account). This answer probably comes the closest, but won't put sent messages in the proper “Sent” folder on the server, and it may not use the proper “From” address either. I have found that to be frustrating when I need to go back and refer to previous mail threads.
2. [QuickMailer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quickmailer/id471864867?mt=12): The app hasn't been updated since 2014, and doesn't seem to support `mailto:` or multiple accounts.
3. [AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83419/is-there-an-app-that-lets-me-send-email-only): This won't integrate with Contacts.app address book, and risks losing the email if something interrupts the process after starting to write it. Seems far too fragile.
4. [QuickSilver](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58730/how-to-quickly-send-new-mail-without-opening-mail-application): The app is pretty much dead, and most of the plugins haven’t been updated in years.
5. “Let.ter”: The app (which I owned and had high hopes for) is not only buggy, but is now abandoned and hasn’t been updated in years.

#### Other Native Mac Mail Applications?

I use [MailMate](https://freron.com) as my regular mail application, and have tried replacing Mailsmith with Apple’s Mail.app and [Mozilla’s Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/). However, neither app seems to accept leaving the incoming mail server information blank. That means they will try to download my email if I enter the correct information, and if I enter incorrect information, they will continually throw error messages.

Are there other Mac email clients that I should try? It seems like most of the mail apps that I’ve heard about recently are for iOS, not Mac, but it’s entirely possible there are others out there that I have overlooked.

*{I will try to update this post as I find and try other mail clients.}*

Comment: Did you consider the Terminal Mail ? Go into Terminal and type `man mail` for help

Comment: I didn't realize I needed to specify that I wasn't looking for terminal apps after the things I said I'm looking for: native Mac application, integration with contacts.app, integration with `mailto` links and other apps that want to use a mail client. I don't think any terminal mail solution comes close to meeting those requirements.

Comment: I thought your priority is the SEND  only ! not a full fledged Mail with GUI and all whistles and bells.

Comment: @TJLuoma    Have you found any solution to this since?   I came exactly across the same problem, but nothing seems to be out there to accomplish this.

Comment: @jan Unfortunately no. Nothing seems to be suitable for this use-case. Disappointing.